# How to Use RustEmbed to load Images into an fltk app?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the [RustEmbed](https://github.com/pyros2097/rust-embed) crate to embed some svg icons into my executable. I don't see any documentation on how to turn the data returned from `Asset::get("icons/some.svg")` into  an actual image. My GUI library is [fltk](https://docs.rs/fltk/0.15.6/fltk/index.html), and I want to create an `fltk::image::SvgImage` using `Asset` but `SvgImage::new()` loads an svg from a path, not raw byte data. Because it loads the svg from a path and not from raw byte data, does that mean I can't use RustEmbed for embedding the icons into my target build?

I want to do this because I feel like embedding my image assets into the executable will help avoid IO errors when the path of my executable is changed during deployment/install/build. I thought this one of the intentions of the RustEmbed crate.

```rust
use rust_embed::RustEmbed;
use fltk::image::*;
#[derive(RustEmbed)]
#[folder = "examples/public/"]
struct Asset;

fn main() {
  let svg = Asset::get("icons/eye.svg").unwrap();
  println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(svg.as_ref()));
  //just prints some long array of numbers [60, 115,118,...60,47,115]
  wind_svg = SvgImage::load(svg).unwrap();
}
```

gives error:

```
the trait `AsRef<std::path::Path>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<Cow<'_, [u8]>>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that fltk::image::SvgImage has a [`from_data()`](https://docs.rs/fltk/0.15.4/fltk/image/struct.SvgImage.html) function. This can be used create load the svg from byte data:

```rust
use rust_embed::RustEmbed;
use fltk::image::*;
#[derive(RustEmbed)]
#[folder = "examples/assets/"]
struct Asset;

fn main() {
  let bytes = Asset::get("icons/eye.svg").unwrap();
  let svg = SvgImage::from_data(std::str::from_utf8(&bytes).unwrap()).unwrap();
}
```

For more useful information on dependencies check out [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7d1vdm/whats_the_standard_way_of_bundling_resource_files/) reddit thread.